# Principal ideal of an integrally closed domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain and $S$ be an integral domain that contains $R$. Assume that $a\in S$ is integral over $R$. Prove that $I=\left\{ f\left(x\right)\in R\left[x\right]\mid f\left(a\right)=0\right\} $ is a principal ideal of $R[x].$

I only know that $R[x]$ is also an integrally closed integral domain and $a$ is a root of a monic polynomial of $R[x]$. So if $g(x)$ is a monic polynomial of $R[x]$ then $g(a)=0$.

Help me a hint.

Thank for any insight.

Comment: You know the proof when $R$ is a field. Try to imitate it.

Comment: Ehm, if $R$ is a field, $R[x]$ is PID. It's easy to prove that $I$ is an ideal of $R[x]$. Since $R[x]$ is PID, $I$ is a principal ideal of $R[x]$.

Comment: I think this case is so trivial. Can you give me another hint?

Comment: Help me. Please.

Comment: Yes and how do you prove that the polynomial ring is a PID?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: You can post a question and I will answer. For a hint, let $I$ be an ideal of field $R[x]$, let $n$ be the smallest integer in the set of all degrees of all polynomial of $I$, show that $I=<f(x)>$ with $f$ is the polynomial of degree $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$, the field of fractions of $R$, and $f\in I$ monic. We should have $p\mid f$ in $K[x]$, and by Gauss' lemma $p\mid f$ in $R[x]$. Now it's easy to show that $I=(p)$.

Comment: Can you tell me about Gauss's lemma? The Gauss's lemma that I known doesn't like this.

Comment: If a product of two monic polynomials from $K[x]$ is in $R[x]$, then both polynomials are in $R[x]$ (of course, $R$ is integrally closed and $K$ field of fractions of $R$). See [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=1AZfvv-Ava0C&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=gauss+lemma+normal+domain&source=bl&ots=unQutBUkoe&sig=J3d6RTklB7GrJLNGHbQ1TGwOVDc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xJmMUtCDBo6o0wWr9oCYCg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=gauss%20lemma%20normal%20domain&f=true), for example. (Btw, normal = integrally closed.)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I think integrally closed is a special feature. So can it imply many other special features like PID? Such as prime ideal imply principal?

Comment: @user109584: No, only nearly. If $R$ is integrally closed domain we know that $R[x]$ is also. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R[x]$ such that $P\cap R=\left\{ 0\right\}$ and $P$ contains a monic polynomial. You can check that $P$ is principal.