# Non-uniqueness of minimal polynomial for integral extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $R$ be an integral domain, let $S \supset R$ be an extension of $R$ and let $x \in S$ be integral over $R$, i.e. there is a monic polynomial $P \in R[T]$ such that $P(x)=0$.

The kernel of the evaluation ring morphism $ev_x : R[T] \to R$ is a non-zero ideal $J$ of $R[T]$.
Let $m$ be the minimum of the degrees of the non-zero polynomials in $J$. 
There must be a polynomial $P_1 \in J$ of degree $m$, but it might not be the only such polynomial (even if we add "up to a constant").

Whence **my question** : Is there an example of $R$ and $x \in S$ where there are two "non-associated" non-zero polynomials of minimal degree in $J$ ? In other words, I want $P_1, P_2 \in J$ of degree $m$ but there is no $c \in R$ such that $P_2=cP_1$.

Comments :

1) If $R[T]$ is a PIR (equivalently $R$ is field [I assumed that $R$ is a domain, so it can't be e.g. a product of fields]), then $P_1$ is unique and generates $J$.

2) Let $P_2 \in J$ be another polynomial of degree $m$. Then $P_1 - P_2$ might not be of smaller degree! Indeed, they might not be monic polynomials.

3) Maybe we could look at the extension of $J$ in $Frac(R)[T]$ (which is a PID)...

Comment: I think it doesn't even have to be true, that there is a $P_1 \in J$ such that $P_1$ is normalized..

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574432/principal-ideal-of-an-integrally-closed-domain

Comment: @user26857 : thank you. Would you have a counter-example when $R$ is not integrally closed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$  be a field, and $S=k[x]$ the polynomial ring in one indeterminate $x$ over $k$.
In the ring extension  $R=k[x^2,x^3]\subset S=k[x]$  the element $x\in S$ is integral over $R$ but is killed by the two different minimal monic polynomials in $R[T]$:  $$T^2-x^2,\quad T^2+x^2T-x^2-x^3                $$

Comment: This looks very nice! 1) Don't you mean $T^2+x^3T-x^2-x^4$ for the second polynomial?  2) I would say that in my case, the minimal degree is $m=1$, since $P_1(T) = x^3 T - x^4 \in J = ker(ev_x) \subset R[T]$ annihilates $x \in S$, so I'm not sure that this completely address my question. I did not require the polynomials _of minimal degree_ to be monic (i.e. this is not "of minimal degree among the monic polynomials annihilating $x$").

Comment: Dear Alphonse,  there was indeed a typo that I have just corrected. And you are right also that I gave an example of  different **monic** polynomials of the same degree annihilating $x$

Comment: @Alphonse I don't understand what your comment means: $P_2(T)=x^2T-x^3$ is also good, and I can't see how $P_2=cP_1$ for some $c\in R$. (As you can notice $x\notin R$.)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: Dear @user26857:  If you transform your comment into an answer  I would be very glad to upvote  it, since it is you (and  not I)  who solved   Alphonse's **real** question.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, I'm sure you have noticed what I said immediately after getting what the OP wanted. (+1)

Comment: Dear @user26857, no, I had not noticed  anything, but shhhh... don't tell anyone :-)